# Index Match with and If

Tags: excel

If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated.

I cant get my code to work it keeps bringing back an answer of "no" I need it to complete the following index and match if the initial If criteria is met but it isn't working.

```
   {=IF('All Data'!E3:E6= "1",(INDEX('All Data'!$F$3:$F$6,MATCH($G$11,'All Data'!$D$3:$D$6,0))),"no")}
```

Thanks 
Paula

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this to work through using multiple criteria in my index match

```
    =INDEX('All Data'!$F$3:$F$190,MATCH(1,($H$5='All Data'!$E$3:$E$6)*($G$11='All Data'!$D$3:$D$6),0))
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do but I'm glad you figured it out.